# Build edges with similarity value from adjacency matrix using NetworkX?

Tags: python-3.x, graph, networkx, adjacency-matrix

I have build a graph from nodes like:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({
            'id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
            'a': [55, 2123, -19.3, 9, -8], 
            'b': [21, -0.1, 0.003, 4, 2.1]
        })

import networkx as nx
G = nx.Graph()
for i, attr in data.set_index('id').iterrows():
    G.add_node(i, **attr.to_dict())
```

I have calculated similarity matrix (by excluding the `id` column).

```
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity

# Calculate the pairwise cosine similarities 
S = cosine_similarity(data.drop('id', axis=1))

T  = S.tolist()
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(T)
```

Here is my adj matrix:

```
adj_mat = pd.DataFrame(df.to_numpy(), index=data['id'], columns=data['id'])
```

Now, how can I "attach" and connect the nodes using this adj_mat? For example I want node with id = 1 to connect to node with id = 2 with an edge with a similarity parameter equals to the similarity calculated in adj matrix.

Please advise how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by firstly building the graph from adj matrix:

```
G = nx.Graph()
G = nx.from_pandas_adjacency(df_adj)
```

Then looping on my nodes data, update the nodes with their attributes (and remove the self loops):

```
G.remove_edges_from(nx.selfloop_edges(G))
for i, attr in data.set_index('id').iterrows():
    G.add_node(i, **attr.to_dict())
```

Hope it will help others :)